# Difference between global and regional IP addresses in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

AWS publishes a [list](https://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips) of CloudFront's IP addresses (taken from AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html)). It contains a JSON document with 2 keys:

- **CLOUDFRONT_GLOBAL_IP_LIST**
- **CLOUDFRONT_REGIONAL_EDGE_IP_LIST**

What's the difference between these lists (global and regional)?

- Which IPs are hit when the web-client accesses a CloudFront distribution: *global* or *regional edge* ones?
- Which IPs do actually hit your origin (e.g. with `CachingDisabled` cache policy, etc.)?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you have two sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFront (CF) has [two types of caches](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc):

- Edge caches - this is the first level of caching layer for CF. This is the layer most people are familiar with and consider when working with CF.
- [Regional caches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html#CloudFrontRegionaledgecaches) - this is the second level, between your origin and CF distro. If edge caches have a miss, AWS can check regional cashes for your data, before going directly to your origin.

So your origin can get hit from both IP ranges.

Comment: AWS documentation does not provide a definitive explanation on this matter (it doesn't say POPs or regional edge cache ips hit your origin, it says CloudFront does), so your answer is just guessing. I was looking for smb who has done some experiments (e.g. with CachingDisabled cache policy, etc.)

Comment: @maslick Its not a guess. That's why you have two sets of IPs in `CloudFront's IP addresses`. If the regional caches did not hit your origin ever, there would be no reason to least these IPs.